# sql strictly equals, is there something?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL server ignore case in a where expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224364/sql-server-ignore-case-in-a-where-expression)

basically I need to check something like  this

```
select * from users where name = @name, pass = @pass
```

the problem is that  `'pass' = 'pAsS'`

is there something more strict for string comparison in sql (ms sql-server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's down to your collation, which it would seem is case insensitive. For example, the standard collation is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, where the `CI` means case insensitive. You can force a different collaction for a different comparison:

```
select  *
from    users
where   name = @name
and     pass COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = @pass COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Incidentally, you shouldn't be storing passwords in your database - you should be salting and hashing them.

Comment: Still, when comparing the hashed passwords, the comparison should be case sensetive. :)

Comment: Yes indeed - case sensitive binary!

Comment: thumbed up but yes case sensitivity in hashed as well is required

Answer (score 3):

As several others have already posted you can use collations in your query or change the collation of your "pass" column to be case sensitive.  You may also change your query to use the VARBINARY type instead of changing collation:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE name = @name
AND pass = @pass
AND CAST(pass AS VARBINARY(50)) = CAST(@pass AS VARBINARY(50))
```

Note that I left in the `pass = @pass` clause.  Leaving this line in the query allows SQL Server to use any index on the pass column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a case sensitive collation for the comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE name = @name, pass = @pass
COLLATE  SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS
```

See [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1032) article for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It's all to do with database collation.

This should help you:

```
select * from users where name = @name, pass = @pass COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

There is some information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330962(SQL.90).aspx#intlftrql2005_topic6) regarding collations in SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

For case sensitive you need to specify the collation in your query. Something like:

```
select * from users where name = @name, pass = @pass COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a **binary collation** to ensure an exact match.

```
WHERE pass = @pass COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```