# SQL LOWER (or UPPER) vs Like

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table that isn't going to get very big and contains the name of a *client account* and a *user's alias*. I'm importing this information from production in order to run a few reports.

To help out with management of the table contents, I'm adding a simple AddUser stored procedure where first I want to check if the *client account/alias* combo already exists in the table.

Since I want this check to be case insensitive, I considered using `LOWER` or `like` when comparing the values.

Probably in this scenario, I wouldn't see a big difference either way with regard to performance, but it made me wonder if there is a best practice when doing this sort of thing.

many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` is going to be much faster than the conversion using `LOWER`, especially the longer the name.

Comment: If you use `LIKE Name%` then yes - that might use an index, if present. If you use `LIKE %Name%` then pretty certainly no, since that expression will not be able to use any indices if present....

Answer (score 2):

Is the database instance set to a case-sensitive collation for strings?  If not, none of that is necessary as all comparisons will be case insensitive.

See here: [SQL server ignore case in a where expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224364/sql-server-ignore-case-in-a-where-expression)

Comment: cool, so regardless, I can always provide an alternate collation.

Comment: Yes, but generally speaking most SQL Server instances are case insensitive, so you generally won't have to worry about it.

Comment: @Joe, until you have to. For instance, postgres is case sensitive always. MySQL is case sensitive on Linux and case insensitive on windows.

Answer (score 2):

`lower(name) = 'Somename'` will not use an index, whereas `name like 'some%'` might.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server, you can use a regular compare (=). Unless you change the default setting, SQL Server string comparisons are case insensitive.

Comment: This is often true but not always the case, you have to be using a collation that specifies case insensitivity for it to work.  You can find out your collation by running `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('dbName', 'Collation')` which will output results something like `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` the second to last part of that string tells us, CI = case insensitive and CS = case sensitive

Comment: Many sql server instances I've worked in have been set to case sensitive. To be safe, I'd like to know a best practice if there is one. Looks like I can set an alternate collation on the query regardless of the current setting.