# SQL- Ignore case while searching for a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-insensitive, sql-like, ignore-case

I have the following data in a Table

PriceOrderShipped

PriceOrderShippedInbound

PriceOrderShippedOutbound

In SQL I need to write a query which searches for a string in a table. While searching for  a string it should ignore case. For the below mentioned SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME FROM myTable WHERE COL_NAME LIKE '%PriceOrder%'
```

gives all the above data, whereas

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME FROM myTable WHERE COL_NAME LIKE '%Priceorder%'
```

doesn't give.

Eg. when I search for 'PriceOrder' or 'priceOrder' it works but 'priceorder' or 'Priceorder' doesn't work.
I have tried with the below query using COLLATE, but its not working. Do let me know where im going wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME FROM myTable WHERE 
COL_NAME COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE '%Priceorder%'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL server ignore case in a where expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224364/sql-server-ignore-case-in-a-where-expression)

Answer (score 382, accepted):

Use something like this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME FROM myTable WHERE UPPER(COL_NAME) LIKE UPPER('%PriceOrder%')
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME FROM myTable WHERE LOWER(COL_NAME) LIKE LOWER('%PriceOrder%')
```

Comment: I think you should always compare strings capitalized (UPPER) as best practice. Google "turkish i"

Comment: Like to know does your answer has any performance issue by converting a column value to `UPPER` or `LOWER` case then using the `LIKE` to search ?

Comment: Actually you would have to compare both UPPER and LOWER variants because some characters have different representations in upper case but the same representation in lower case. For other characters, the opposite may be true. Java mentions the Georgian alphabet specifically as reason for doing an additional toLowerCase() in its case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach causes a full table scan as described in this post: https://alvinalexander.com/sql/sql-select-case-insensitive-query-queries-upper-lower. An index search can not be applied, as the filtered column is modified by the UPPER/LOWER function.

Comment: Setting a collation (before creating the index) seems to be the better approach if query performance with upper/lower is not sufficient.

Comment: Is the LIKE operator case sensitive in MySQL?. In my understanding it is not.

Answer (score 50):

Like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME FROM myTable WHERE COL_NAME iLIKE '%Priceorder%'
```

In postgresql.

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:sql-server] so a postgres answer isn't relevant.

Comment: Thanks. I applied same logic on Apache Spark and works correctly

Answer (score 13):

See this similar question and answer to searching with case insensitivity - [SQL server ignore case in a where expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224364/sql-server-ignore-case-in-a-where-expression)

Try using something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME 
FROM myTable 
WHERE COL_NAME COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE '%priceorder%'
```

Comment: it din't work I get SQL query not properly ended before Collate

Comment: @Miguel-F.. it is working fine but how does it differ from
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME 
FROM myTable 
WHERE COL_NAME  LIKE '%priceorder%'
because this is also working fine for me..

Comment: I would advice using 'SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AS_KI_WI' instead. It's not case sensetive for a seach.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AS_KI_WI` as your collation. The one you specify in your question is explictly case sensitive.

You can see a list of collations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

The like operator is not case sensitive in almost all the SQL compilers. If you are still not getting case sensitive results then go with iLike operator. Also you can compare it by changing the case using Upper() method.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME FROM myTable WHERE COL_NAME iLIKE '%PriceOrder%'
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME FROM myTable WHERE UPPER(COL_NAME) LIKE UPPER('%PriceOrder%')
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME FROM myTable WHERE LOWER(COL_NAME) LIKE LOWER('%PriceOrder%')
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone using ORACLE can be changes at database level itself

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;  
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;
```

Note:- Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution which I use.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN ~* '.*search_keyword_any_case.*'
```

This will also check for substring.
Overall the best solution that I came across from the internet. I use the same to implement substring case insensitive search for table's columns.

Answer (score 1):

LIKE and ILIKE allow pattern matching within character-based column data. Their syntax is identical, but LIKE is case-sensitive, while ILIKE is case-insensitive.
i am using postgresql, it work fine for me. i.e

`SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME FROM myTable WHERE COL_NAME iLIKE '%Priceorder%'`

Answer (score 0):

ALTERNATE & BEST SOLUTION:
You can also use a specific "collation" like utf8 > utf8_unicode_ci. Then ALL QUERIES will be insensitive to case. But the data can be in upper case in some places. So just be sure that there is no twin with different cases possible (like using a UNIQUE column to be sure).

QUERY Example:
https://prnt.sc/1vjwxd1
Table design & collation used : https://prnt.sc/1vjx3h5.

"A good design of Database can save you a lot of work in queries" - Me :)

Comment: My coalition is utf8_general_ci and the queries are still case sensitive