# How do I select all rows that have a particular key in a JSON field?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to select all rows in a table where my "object_details" JSON field contains one of the following keys: "subject", "Subject", "SUBJECT".

With the following sample rows:

```
datetime             | object_details                                             
---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
2019-07-21T00:01:34Z | {"Sender": "bob@example.com", "Subject": "First email!"}   
2019-07-23T09:30:01Z | {"Sender": "carol@example.com", "subject": "Second email!"}
2019-07-27T22:23:15Z | {"Sender": "dave@example.com", "protocol": "SMTP"}
```

I'm expecting the result to provide only these rows:

```
datetime             | object_details                                             
---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
2019-07-21T00:01:34Z | {"Sender": "bob@example.com", "Subject": "First email!"}   
2019-07-23T09:30:01Z | {"Sender": "carol@example.com", "subject": "Second email!"}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the second answer in the following link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082575/sql-ignore-case-while-searching-for-a-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: @SaiKrishna: that question has nothing to do with what Jed wants to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the exists operator `?|`  that takes an array of keys as its input for that:

```
select *
from the_table
where object_details ?| array['subject', 'Subject', 'SUBJECT'];
```

Comment: Wouldn't this catch an edge case where the word subject is included in one of the stored json values, but not as any of the keys, or as part of a key name? If this is the case perhaps including the quotes and colon? `array['"subject":', '"Subject":', '"SUBJECT"':]` would force a more precise match?

Comment: @Andrew: no, the exists operator only looks at the keys, never at the values.

Answer (score -1):

Using MySQL this can be done using this syntax.

```
   SELECT *
    FROM the_table
    WHERE LOCATE("subject", object_details) > 0 ;
```

PostgreSQL would be (PostgreSQL is case sensitive):-

```
 SELECT *
   FROM the_table
   WHERE POSITION('subject' IN LOWER(object_details)) > 0;
```